# How to click the CSV button in a website and download the data in python

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am trying to download the CSV and JSON data from following website: https://worldpopulationreview.com/countries/countries-by-gdp/#worldCountries

## How to simulate clicking csv file?

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from lxml import html,etree

url = "https://worldpopulationreview.com/countries/countries-by-gdp/#worldCountries"

# now I am not sure, how to click csv button of actual website
# also I am not sure how it will download the csv file
# to DOWNLOADS as like when I click the page
```

## I can scrape webpage, but I want to learn clicking of button

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = "https://worldpopulationreview.com/countries/countries-by-gdp/#worldCountries"

r = requests.get(url)
df = pd.read_html(r.text)[0]
df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to download `pip install selenium`
If using Chrome then download the Chrome driver here - [Chrome driver](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=81.0.4044.69/). And then find the xpath of the button/link, I used inspect element to find the xpath:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/xxx/Downloads/chromedriver-1')
driver.get('https://worldpopulationreview.com/countries/countries-by-gdp')#put here the adress of your page
btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/a[2]')
btn.click()
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/xxx/Downloads/data.csv')
print(df.head())
driver.close()

   rank         country        imfGDP           unGDP  gdpPerCapita          pop
0     1   United States  2.219812e+13  18624475000000    67063.2695   331002.651
1     2           China  1.546810e+13  11218281029298    10746.7828  1439323.776
2     3           Japan  5.495420e+12   4936211827875    43450.1405   126476.461
3     4         Germany  4.157120e+12   3477796274497    49617.1450    83783.942
4     6  United Kingdom  2.927080e+12   2647898654635    43117.5725    67886.011
```

Image to find the xpath: 
[image: Xpath]

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it gives me following error `WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <a>...</a> is not clickable at point`. Have you tested the code, does it work for you?

Comment: Yes, i have following executable `/usr/local/bin/chromedriver`

Comment: Also, will you enlighten me why you have so many div/div/div, will you post the screenshot how to get the required XPath, i will appreciate that.

Comment: Try finding the xpath of the button by inspecting it in Chrome

Comment: Right click on the CSV button and hit inspect, then right click on the html and Copy full xpath.

Comment: I did but still could not find `div[1]`, if you post the screensot of inspect, I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use selenium in order to simulate the click on the csv download button 
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#example-explained